# Javascript / Ajax: assigning value to a new object and deleting one of the element

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making an Ajax request and assigning the dataset of this request to a new object {} using Object.assign() method and subsequently wants to delete one of the item in this new object. But when I console.log() my original dataset, the value is also deleted from there aswell. Why is that even when I'm assigning it using Object.assign() method? How can I stop JS to do that?

```
$.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'filtered_financial' %}",
                method: 'GET',
                data : {
                    airline_category: 1,
                        },
                success: function(dataset){

    var dataCopy = Object.assign({}, dataset);

    delete dataCopy.financial_year

    console.log(dataset) // financial_year element is deleted

    )};
```